# Deleting nodes with tie=1 in a large NetworkX graph

Tags: python, graph-theory, networkx, filterfunction

I have made large graph with NetworkX with about 20,000 nodes. I would like to delete nodes with only one tie (or zero ties) to try to reduce the clutter. Since it is a very large graph I do not know the nodes by name or ID that have tie=1 or 0.

Does anyone know how to delete these nodes without specifying the node ID or name?

[image]

Comment: Do you care about whether the nodes left over after deleting might now have degree 0 or 1?

Comment: Another question: are you wanting to actually delete them from the network, or just not include them in the drawing?

Answer (score 4):

Iterating on a `Graph` `g` yields all of `g`'s nodes, one at a time -- I believe you can't alter `g` during the iteration itself, but you can selectively make a list of nodes to be deleted, then remove them all:

```
to_del = [n for n in g if g.degree(n) <= 1]
g.remove_nodes_from(to_del)
```

Comment: Just 2 notes: 1) after this deletion, nodes which originally had degree 2 or higher could now have degree 0 or 1.  Whether this is a problem depends on the OP's goals.   2) you could alter `g` as part of a for loop with `g.remove_node(node)`, but this could end up with more nodes deleted as some have their degrees reduced by the process.  Repeatedly going through and deleting all such nodes results in the 2-core of the graph.

Comment: @Joel, wrt (1), definitely -- if the OP's looking for the 2-core, then the `k_core` method is no doubt a better approach; that's just not what I got from the Q, but it's ambiguous enough that you could well be right.  Re (2), I wasn't sure if you're allowed to alter the very graph you're looping on -- in the more general case of Python containers you aren't, but maybe you're right that `networkx` chooses to be an exception to that (I can't see it documented anywhere, though -- any URL about it?).

Comment: (1) - wasn't directed necessarily at you, but rather in case the OP or some other user were looking at this.  (2) yes and no - you can loop through `G.nodes()` which is just a list of the nodes.  If you loop through `G.nodes_iter()` or `for n in G` [which I think just maps directly to `for n in G.nodes_iter()`] it will fail.

Comment: @Joel oh yeah, of course if you've got a now-standalone list of nodes, no matter how originally obtained, you can alter the graph while looping on the list -- it's just often an inferior approach due to needing to materialize that whole large list, hence I usually prefer to loop `for item in container:` and can't alter `container` within that specific loop!-)

Comment: And just to be clear - my main concern when I originally raised (2) was that if someone were to try looping and deleting at the same time they almost certainly wouldn't get what they were after.  It would delete the nodes that are originally degree <2 and some but not all of the nodes that later get their degree reduced below 2, and the result would depend on the arbitrary order of `G.nodes()`.  So it's not a matter of "it's not possible", but rather "it's a bad idea".

Answer (score 3):

I think you're after this one-liner:

```
G= nx.k_core(G,k=2)
```

---

You should be aware that if you delete some nodes, you'll have new nodes whose degree is just 1 or 0.  If you want to repeat this process until no such nodes exist, you're generating the "k-core" with k=2.  That is you're generating the largest network for which all nodes have degree at least 2.  This is a built-in function:

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.fast_gnp_random_graph(10000,0.0004) #erdos renyi graph, average degree = 4
G = nx.k_core(G,k=2)
```

---

You could instead do:

```
for node in G.nodes():
    if G.degree(node)<2:
        G.remove_node(node)
```

but this would yield a different result from the 2-core I described above, and a different result from A Martelli's as well since some of the later nodes in the list may originally have degree 2 but be reduced to 1 before you reach them.  And it wouldn't be as clean because it creates the list `G.nodes()` rather than using a nicer iterator (if you're in networkx v1.x and you aren't altering a graph in the loop, it's usually better to loop through the nodes with `G.nodes_iter()` rather than `G.nodes()`)