# Retaining specific nodes while using k-core in Networkx

Tags: python-3.x, graph, networkx

I've a random graph created using Netwrokx and I want to delete nodes with degree less than 2 except for 2 user-defined nodes that have degree = 1. To remove all nodes with degree < 2, I could use Networkx's `k-core`. But I am not sure how to retain the 2 user-defined nodes. For example, the following code generates,

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# fig 1
G = nx.gnm_random_graph(n=20, m=30, seed=1)
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, pos=nx.spring_layout(G))
plt.show()

G = nx.k_core(G, k=2)
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, pos=nx.spring_layout(G))
plt.show()
```

Figure 1:

[image]

Figure 2:

[image]

I would like to ask for suggestions on how to retain 2 user-defined nodes:
e.g

```
retain_node_ids = [1,2]
```

EDIT:

I could use `remove_nodes_from` as suggested below. But if we delete nodes with degree < 2  we may end up with new nodes, which originally had degree >=2, with degree <2. To repeat the process until no nodes with degree < 2 is found, `k-core` has been used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can do it:

```
degrees = nx.classes.degree(G)
G.remove_nodes_from([node
                     for node in G.nodes
                     if node not in retain_node_ids and degrees[node] <= 2])
```

Of course this piece of code does not find a maximal subgraph (as `k_core` function does): it simply remove all nodes with degree less than or equal to 2, and which are not in the `retain_node_ids` list.

---

EDIT:
You can add two fake nodes, connect nodes to retain to them, compute the k-core and then get rid of them:

```
G.add_edges_from([(u, v) for u in retain_node_ids for v in (n, n+1)])
G = nx.k_core(G, k=2)
G.remove_nodes_from([n, n+1])
```

[image: Figure 1]
[image: Figure 2]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. But nodes which had degree >= 2 in the original graph may now have degree < 2.  I would like to remove those too. Please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29268491/deleting-nodes-with-tie-1-in-a-large-networkx-graph)

Comment: @Natasha Please update your question as you were not very specific....